# Autoincremented 2 level of multiindex pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: example]
First of all let me explain the attached photo. It's just a quick explanation of what I want to achieve. This topic isn't about Excel at all.
I have a dataset loaded with pandas lib. Data was clustered so you can see a column in picture.
What I want to do is slightly reorganize dataset so it has smth like multiindex with 2 levels: "cluster" and "sub_index". Sub_index has to be a part of complex index (as shown in picture), so this multiindex has to uniquely identify a row.
Once again, using pandas.
Seems to be an easy stuff but I'm stuck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see a multiindex here.

Comment: You're result can be achieved with `df.groupby('cluster').cumcount().add(1)`

Comment: please show us the pandas data frame you're using & the output in text format, not a screenshot of a mockup in excel.